# Swift playground and LeetCode OJ

Tags: swift

```
class Solution {
    func reverseString(s: String) -> String {
    let rev = String(s.characters.reverse())
    print(rev)
 }
}
```

The error i get is:
Missing return in a function expected to return String

The same function in Leetcode OJ gives me the following error:

Line 4: cannot call value of non-function type 'Distance' (aka 'Int')

While i type the following in the Playground it works fine:

```
var str = "Hello"
let rev  = String(str.characters.reverse())
```

I can't seem to figure out the solution to this and why it behaves differently in the playground with the function return type and in Leetcode OJ.

Swift noob and any help would be most appreciated! thanks

Comment: `reverseString ` returns a `String` but you are not returning `rev` or `String(s.characters.reverse()`  at the end of function, only printing value.

Comment: class Solution {
        func reverseString(s: String) -> String {
        
            let rev = String(s.characters.reverse())
        
            return rev
 
        
        }
        }

      reverseString("hello") 
 
error: Playground execution failed: MyPlayground.playground:11:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'reverseString'
reverseString("hello")
^~~~~~~~~~~~~


Also im sorry about the formatting. learning slowly :/

Comment: You are saying that your `reverseString` function will return a `String` but you are returning nothing. Add `return rev` after `print(rev)` line.

Comment: `class Solution {
    func reverseString(s: String) -> String {
        
        let rev = String(s.characters.reverse())
        
        return rev
 
        
    }
}

reverseString("hello")`

Playground execution failed: MyPlayground.playground:11:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'reverseString'
reverseString("hello")
^~~~~~~~~~~~~  @K.Nimo

Comment: @rohanKumar  The code in your comments defines `reverseString` as belonging to a `Solution` instance but you're calling it as if it were a global function.

Comment: Thanks @PhillipMills . much appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Solution {
func reverseString(s: String) -> String {
    let rev = String(s.characters.reverse())
    print(rev)
    return rev
    }
}

var str = Solution()
str.reverseString("Hello")
```

If you intend to add custom methods which works on a a particular `Type` than create an extension on that Type type.

```
extension String {
    // you methods
}
```

For example:

```
extension String {
    func length() -> Int {
        return self.characters.count
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as class function on String type

```
let greetings: String = "Hello"
greetings.length()  // 5
```

Comment: Thanks @K.Nimo! It worked.

So the last two lines... 
`var str = Solution()`
this is to make an instance of the Solution class? 

and `str.reverseString("Hello")` 
is to access the reverse string function of the instance of the Solution class (which is str in this case) ?